# How to rename a new project in Neo4j Desktop?

Tags: neo4j, project, rename

When creating a new project in Neo4j Desktop, it names them "Project", "Project 1", "Project 2", etc.

Is there a way to rename them to something more descriptive?

Thank you in advance!

--Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are on a project, on the main section, go to the project name, and then a `pencil` will appear. By clicking on it, you will be able to rename the project.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!! Moving the mouse is not something very intuitive to developers :)

Answer (score 3):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648047/1243762) by logisima is correct, I just highlighted the edit icon (pencil) in red to make it more obvious.

[image]